# Axios with OMDB API, getting 401 Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to implement the OMDB API in a development application and in the console I continue to get a 401 Unauthorized error. I have an active `apikey` from the OMDB API website, but I must say the usage is confusing me.

What I got in the email looked like this:

http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt12345678&apikey=1234cae2

and I have tried to implement it in various ways, in particular like this:

```
/** catch a submission of the form
 * and then take the value and call a function getMovies to reach out
 * to API
 *
 **/
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#searchForm').on('submit', (e) => {
    // put this in a variable
    // console.log($('#searchText').val());
    let searchText = $('#searchText').val();
    getMovies(searchText);
    // stops form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

function getMovies(searchText) {
  // console.log(searchText);
  axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s='+searchText).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

but I am unclear as to whether I do need to append the api in there and if so, which set of numbers is the api key? I have tried both the `12345678&` and the `1234cae2`.

After all this, I am not sure if the problem is my axios library which I am pulling in via Content Delivery Network like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Movie Info</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">MovieInfo</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h3 class="text-center">Search for Any Movie</h3>
      <form id="searchForm">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchText" placeholder="Search Movie...">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="movies" class="row"></div>
  </div>

  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: apikey is 1234cae2. Shouldnt you pass that in the request?

Comment: one query why are you using axios if you are already using jQuery. jQuery does comes with an ajax api which also supports promises

Comment: hmm, good point @karthick.

Comment: @karthick, would it be implemented like this: `axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=1234cae2='+searchText)`, I am still getting a 401 error.

Comment: try this in your browser http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=1234cae2&plot=short&t=Oceans

Comment: you should do the same in ajax call so it will be "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apiKey=1234cae2"+ "&t=" + searchText.

Comment: @karthick, that worked. Please post as your answer.

Comment: Cool man... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search omdb api you have to provide apiKey and also pass the same in the ajax request

example api
http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=1234cae2&plot=short&t=Oceans

example ajax
axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?apiKey=1234cae2'+ '&t='+  searchText).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  })

The list of parameters to be passed is in the parameter sections
http://www.omdbapi.com/

Note: I am separating url with the parameters so you can use whatever parameter you like id, title or search sting. Also jQuery does comes with an ajax api which also supports promises. So axios might be an extra load here.

Answer (score -1):

This works perfectly like this. It would not work any other way for some reason.

```
axios.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${searchText}&apikey=${APIKeyHere}`)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$(document).ready(() => {

    $('#searchForm').on('submit', (e) => {

        let searchText = $('#searchText').val();
        getMovies(searchText);
        e.preventDefault();

    });
});

function getMovies(searchText) {

    axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?s='+searchText + '&apikey=9be27fce').then((response) => {

        console.log(response);
        let movies =response.data.Search;
        let output = '';
        $.each(movies, (index,movie) => {

            output +=` 
                <div class = "col-md-3">
                    <div class = "well text-center">
                        <img src = "${movie.Poster}">
                        <h5>${movie.Title}</h5>
                         <a onclick="movieSelected('${movie.imdbID}')" class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Movie Details</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;

        });

        $('#movies').html(output);
     })

     .catch((err) => {

        console.log(err);


     });
}

function movieSelected(id){

    sessionStorage.setItem('movieId', id);
    window.location = 'movie.html';
    return false;
}


function getMovie(){

    let movieId = sessionStorage.getItem('movieId');


    axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?i='+movieId+'&apikey=9be27fce').then((response) => {


        let movie = response.data;
        console.log(movie);
        let output = `

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                   <img src ="${movie.Poster}" class="thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <h2>${movie.Title}</h2>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Genre:</strong>${movie.Genre}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Released:</strong>${movie.Released}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Rated:</strong>${movie.Rated}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>IMDB Rating:</strong>${movie.imdbRating}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Director:</strong>${movie.Director}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Writer:</strong>${movie.Writer}</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><strong>Actors:</strong>${movie.Actors}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="well">
                <h3>Plot</h3>
                ${movie.Plot}

                <hr>
                <a href="http://imdb.com/title/${movie.imdbID}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">View IMDB
                </a>
                <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-default"> Go Back To Search</a>


                </div>


            </div>
         `;

        document.querySelector('#movie').innerHTML = output;
     })

     .catch((err) => {

        console.log(err);


     });
}
```

Comment: What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: To clarify what Styx tried to say in a really indirect way, code only answers are slightly discouraged. They're allowed, it's not that, but answers with a description are preferred. This is also to make OP understand what the code does; remember, not everyone has a good enough understanding of the language (or code in general for that matter) to automatically understand what a given snippet does. Explanations are usually helpful. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256402/6296561